# Spring data manipulation events and Java 8 lambda expressions: don't work together

Tags: spring, lambda, java-8, spring-data-neo4j-4

My question is pretty straightforward. Why this form works:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
    return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent beforeSaveEvent) {
            Object eventEntity = beforeSaveEvent.getEntity();
            if (eventEntity instanceof Node) {
                Node node = (Node) eventEntity;
                node.initUniqueProperties();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And this doesn't work:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
    return beforeSaveEvent -> {
        Object eventEntity = beforeSaveEvent.getEntity();
        if (eventEntity instanceof Node) {
            Node node = (Node) eventEntity;
            node.initUniqueProperties();
        }
    };
}
```

I thought, they are equivalent. But I receive an exception in the second case:

> org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent cannot be
>   cast to org.springframework.data.neo4j.event.BeforeSaveEvent.

Why?

Comment: Apparently, Spring uses Reflection on the listener class to find out the generic type parameter. A thing that works for the reifiable inner class, but fails (not only) with classes generated for lambda expressions.